# Jquery hover get Id issue

Tags: jquery

Hi I have an img and when I hover over it I want it to unhide a div, however It won't work. Here is my attempt.

```
     $("img").hover(
          function () {
          var currentID = $(this).attr('id');
          $('.'+currentID).show();
      },
          function () {
          var currentID = $(this).attr('id');
          $('.'+currentID).hide();
      }
     );
```

Here is the HTML

```
     //intially hidden via display:none

     <div class="Alligator sinensis" style="display:none;border:solid;float:right;">

     //this is the image       
     <img id="Alligator sinensis" class="circular resultss imgs" src="http://media.eol.org/content/2013/02/20/13/27869_orig.jpg">
```

Comment: Try using # instead of .

Comment: that is not a valid id attribute, ids can't have spaces

Comment: it is not working probably because you have a space in the id.

Comment: Is `<img>` child of `<div>` ?

Answer (score 3):

Your ID and class can't have spaces.

```
<div class="AlligatorSinensis" style="display:none;border:solid;float:right;">

 //this is the image       
<img id="AlligatorSinensis" class="circular resultss imgs" src="http://media.eol.org/content/2013/02/20/13/27869_orig.jpg">
```

Comment: @Sushanth--, a class **attribute** can have two spaces, but that creates two classes.  `$('.Alligator sinensis')` searches for children  with the tag `<sinensis>` that have a parent with a class of `Alligator`.

Comment: @Sushanth The class attribute in the HTML can contain spaces, because it can contain multiple classes. An individual class name can't contain a space.

Comment: (Demo code, assuming that `<img>` is not within `<div>` -- http://jsfiddle.net/8N9Ed/)

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the spaces in both the id and the class. The class is actually 2 classes: Alligator + sinensis

Answer (score 0):

Well, apart from markup problems, I don't think you can hover a img inside a div with `display:none;`. So you need to create a parent div for it.

About the Class/Id you cannot have a ID with spaces targeting a Class with spaces, in classes it means 2 didfferent classes. So either remove the space (like I did, or use `_` like: `Alligator_sinensis`

### Check [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/S2PZD/1/)

I would suggest this:

```
$("#outerdiv").hover(function () {
    var currentID = $(this).find('img').attr('id');
    console.log(currentID);
    $('.' + currentID).show();
},

function () {
    var currentID = $(this).find('img').attr('id');
    $('.' + currentID).hide();
});
```

and html:

```
<div id="outerdiv">//intially hidden via display:none
    <div class="Alligatorsinensis" style="display:none;border:solid;float:right;">//this is the image
        <img id="Alligatorsinensis" class="circular resultss imgs" src="http://media.eol.org/content/2013/02/20/13/27869_orig.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Based on the question it doesn't sound like the `<img>` is supposed to be a child of the `<div>`. The `<div>` isn't visible initially, but the `<img>` is, so hovering over it shows the `<div>`

Comment: @nbrooks, I don't hink so. Well it's unclear but anyway the `<div>` is not closed, so `<img>` is a child in that code example.

Comment: You're completely right about the example being unclear...but I think that was just grabbing small snippets to add to the post (the JS style comments in between suggest it wasn't meant to be real markup). If `<img>` wasn't visible OP wouldn't have been able to test code at all, and we would have seen an all together different question `;)`. Just my guess, anyway

Comment: @nbrooks, well one of us may be right... warn me if you get the answer, you will get a +1 from me for reading question better :)